# Convert Python list to dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

I have a Python list like the following:

```
[{'date': '20200101',
  'Samsung': {'positive': 242, 'negative': 28, 'neutral': 69, 'etc': 98}},
 {'date': '20200102',
  'Samsung': {'positive': 270, 'negative': 45, 'neutral': 83, 'etc': 143}},
 {'date': '20200103',
  'Samsung': {'positive': 252, 'negative': 57, 'neutral': 90, 'etc': 113}},
 {'date': '20200104',
  'Samsung': {'positive': 292, 'negative': 57, 'neutral': 134, 'etc': 229}}]
```

I want to change like:

```
   target date       positive  negative neutral etc
0 Samsung 20200101   242       28       69      98
1 Samsung 20200102   270       45       33      143
2 Samsung 20200103   252       57       90      113
3 Samsung 20200104   292       74       134     229
```

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html

Comment: @DogukanLevendoglu, how is  `from_dict` can solve it?

Comment: @adir-abargil I'm sorry you're right. I assumed his dictionary satisfied the DataFrame consturctor's standard.

Answer (score 2):

Here is your data:

```
dd=[{'date': '20200101',
  'Samsung': {'positive': 242, 'negative': 28, 'neutral': 69, 'etc': 98}},
 {'date': '20200102',
  'Samsung': {'positive': 270, 'negative': 45, 'neutral': 83, 'etc': 143}},
 {'date': '20200103',
  'Samsung': {'positive': 252, 'negative': 57, 'neutral': 90, 'etc': 113}},
 {'date': '20200104',
  'Samsung': {'positive': 292, 'negative': 57, 'neutral': 134, 'etc': 229}}]
```

You need to change your dictionnary structure:

```py
new_dict=[]
for record in dd:
  for k ,v in record.items():
    if k == "date":
      new_dict.append({k:v})
    else:
      new_dict[-1].update({"target":k})
      new_dict[-1].update(v)
new_dict
```

Which gives that

```py
[{'date': '20200101',
  'etc': 98,
  'negative': 28,
  'neutral': 69,
  'positive': 242,
  'target': 'Samsung'},
 {'date': '20200102',
  'etc': 143,
  'negative': 45,
  'neutral': 83,
  'positive': 270,
  'target': 'Samsung'},
 {'date': '20200103',
  'etc': 113,
  'negative': 57,
  'neutral': 90,
  'positive': 252,
  'target': 'Samsung'},
 {'date': '20200104',
  'etc': 229,
  'negative': 57,
  'neutral': 134,
  'positive': 292,
  'target': 'Samsung'}]
```

And then pass it to pandas for a dataframe structure

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(new_dict)
df

       date     target  positive    negative    neutral   etc
0   20200101    Samsung     242           28       69     98
1   20200102    Samsung     270           45       83     143
2   20200103    Samsung     252           57       90     113
3   20200104    Samsung     292           57       134    229
```

Comment: you are welcome, please feel free to validate if it's answer your question.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, dont forget to accept it !

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following (lst is your list):

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame(lst)

df2=pd.json_normalize(df['Samsung'])

df['target']=[list(i.keys())[1] for i in lst]

res=pd.concat([df[['target','date']], df2], axis=1)

print(res)
```

Output:

```
    target      date  positive  negative  neutral  etc
0  Samsung  20200101       242        28       69   98
1  Samsung  20200102       270        45       83  143
2  Samsung  20200103       252        57       90  113
3  Samsung  20200104       292        57      134  229
```

Comment: even better, good job, but what if the target is not only samsung?

Comment: this only fox this specific case but not solve case where there is another target..

Comment: @adirabargil thanks for the notice, i adjusted the code

Comment: its still doesnt seems right because of the target is not samsung, its pointless to call 'Samsung' on the dict because its not there... and also, what if the order is not as showen?